# Having trouble with classes Python

Tags: python, class, sorting

this is my assignment:

SortedStringBag(initial_list)   create a new sorted string bag object and give it the initial list of strings. Sort the list. This is the only time you can sort.

print() print all the contents of the list, one per line. Remember it must be sorted at all times.

count(s)    tell how many times string s occurs in this bag. Return 0 if not found at all.

insert(s)   insert string s into the list using O(n) algorithm.

Hint: to sort a python list, simply do:

mylist.sort()

heres what i've done

```
class SortedStringBag:
def __init__(self,initial_list):
    self.ilist = initial_list.sort()
def __str__(self):
    for i in self:
        if self[i]<self[i+1]:
            print(self[i])
def insert(self, s):
    for i in range(len(self.ilist)):
        if self[i] > item:
            self.insert(i, item)
    else:
        self.append(s)
def count(self, s):
    i = 0
    for n in self:
        if s in self[n]:
            i = i+1
```

for some reason I cant get the top of it positioned correctly but it is in my code.

I really don't understand classes, for some reason none of the methods associate with the class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your main problem here is that you are mixing up calling `self` with `self.ilist`, giving you errors like:

```
>>> import StringBag
>>> mylist = StringBag.SortedStringBag([1, 8, 3, -1, 9, 3, 7, 23 , 6])
>>> print mylist
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "testt.py", line 5, in __str__
    for i in self:
TypeError: iteration over non-sequence
>>>
```

However, you have another key error, which is assigning a variable to the value of a method. Methods do not return anything, so trying to assign them will give you a value of `None`:

```
>>> var = [1, 3, 4, 2].sort()
>>> print var
None
>>>
```

Here is your edited code:

```
class SortedStringBag:
    def __init__(self,initial_list):
        self.ilist = sorted(initial_list)
    def __str__(self):
        return '\n'.join([str(item) for item in self.ilist])
    def insert(self, s):
        for i in range(len(self.ilist)):
            if self.ilist[i] > s:
                self.ilist.insert(i, s)
                break
        else:
            self.ilist.append(s)
    def count(self, s):
        i = 0
        for n in self.ilist:
            if s == n:
                i+=1
        return i
```

Runs as:

```
>>> import StringBag
>>> mylist = StringBag.SortedStringBag([1, 8, 3, -1, 9, 3, 7, 23 , 6])
>>> print mylist
-1
1
3
3
6
7
8
9
23
>>> mylist.count(3)
2
>>> mylist.count(2)
0
>>> mylist.insert(4)
>>> print mylist
-1
1
3
3
4
6
7
8
9
23
>>> mylist.count(4)
1
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm just going to have to get used to classes

Comment: @BrandonJerz, if this answer helped you, would you mind accepting it and +1ing it? It gives you reputation too! Just click on the top arrow next to my answer to +1, and the green check mark to accept.